# Is there any algorithm to predict the next question out of QA data?

Tags: python, algorithm, search, optimization, graph

I have a lot of QA data like this where the first value indicates question and the second value is the expected answer to the question (Qn, Am respectively). If any row completed all the questions and answers, it can get the conclusion. The faster to reach the conclusion is better. If you did not answer the expected answer to the question, the row is no longer valid.

```
(Q1, A1), (Q2, A2), (Q3, A3), colclusion 1
(Q1, A2), (Q4, A1), (Q3, A2), colclusion 2
(Q2, A1), (Q1, A2), (Q4, A1), colclusion 3
(Q6, A1), (Q2, A2), (Q1, A1), (Q5, A1) colclusion 4
(Q1, A2), (Q3, A1) colclusion 5
```

I would like to know if there is a smart algorithm to predict the next optimal question to reach the conclusion fast.
So far, I have tried counting the number of questions in all rows and suggest the most common one, it works fine but it does not perform well when all question count is one.

Any tips or advice would be appreciated. 
Thank you very much.

Comment: how is the "next optimal question" determined?  Is the goal to obtain every one of the conclusions?

Comment: The goal is to reach any conclusion as fast as possible by answering all questions correctly and which conclusion is not a problem.
For example, if you have answered (Q1, A1), (Q2, A2) and you only have (Q3, A3) left on the first row. I want my algorithm to ask Q3.

Comment: I have updated the example QAs, I hope it can help explain it better.

Comment: If you are storing your data in a graph as you have tagged it, you could maintain edges between conclusions and *unaswered* questions.  When a question is answered, remove that edge from the graph.  Then, the next optimal question could be found by looking at the conclusion with the lowest degree.  You could keep your edges in a priority queue

Comment: I see. As I am not storing the data as the graph now, I will create it and calculate the degree. It would be great if you know any code snippet or library in Python you think is useful

Comment: [igraph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Igraph) is a general graph library I've used with R and Python

Comment: Does the order for the questions matter? For example, does (Q3, A3), (Q2, A2), (Q1, A1) imply conclusion 1?

Comment: The order of the question does not matter :)